# How do you obtain a security key in Star Wars: The Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I know the security key is optional but I can't seem to figure out how to get one... I tried the in-game vendor but it wouldn't let me even access his stuff.  Also, once you have one, how onerous is moving computer? and do you have to have it every time you log in?

tl:dr: security keys, how do they work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three options:

- Buy the Collector's Edition which comes with a hardware key
- [Buy a hardware key](http://buy.swtor.com/us/#optional-game-add-ons) after the fact. It costs a couple bucks plus shipping. (Presently, $4 USD + shipping.)
- Download the free [iPhone app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/star-wars-old-republic-security/id996685033) or [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bioware.android.apps.authenticator).

Once you register a security key, the login prompt may still say it's optional, but no longer is at that point. Once a security key is registered, it must be used for all future logins.

Both types of keys display a 8 digit number that you type in yourself into the appropriate field in launcher login. It does not require any kind of USB connection or anything.

It is either a physical device (fits on a keychain, etc.) or an app on your mobile device. So it isn't really "moved between" computers; just carried by you. Depending how heavy your mobile device is, and how weak your biceps are, it still shouldn't be much of a problem. :)

Once you login with a registered security key, you will then get access to the in-game security key vendor. Mostly it offers the ability to purchase with in-game credits some, but not all, of the items that come with Collector's or Digital Deluxe editions. See [the short list here](http://www.swtorstrategies.com/2011/12/swtor-security-key-vendor-items.html). "Some examples of the items are the (popular so far) fleet pass which allows you to return to the fleet, a mouse droid (different skin from the Collector’s Edition item), Exchange Bandit (Increase movement speed by 110% Requires: Speeder Piloting Rank 3) and more."

Also see the official site page describing the [security keys](http://www.swtor.com/info/security-key).

Comment: so... what happens if the key breaks or you lose it? are you then shut out of your account forever more?

Comment: @sarge_smith: There is a reset process you can go through. Make sure you know your security question/answers! It will give you a new security key initialization code, with a reset code. That's for the app though; I don't know how lost hardware keys work. But I assume it is the same but you will have to wait for a new key to be purchased and shipped to you.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me point out that the security key is a physical thing, not an in-game item.  It must be purchased (see [Mufasa's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43084/2259) for sources) or installed.

The "security key" is an electronic [security token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token) (usually a keyfob), a self-contained, battery-powered device with a numeric display that will generate a new, [cryptographically secure pseudorandom number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) every minute or so.  They're meant to be portable, though they are a bit bulkier than a typical key:

[image]

"Cryptographically secure" means that, unlike a normal PRNG where given enough "random" numbers, an attacker could quickly predict the next by determining the state of the generator, the number is run through an additional series of steps that effectively hide the state of the machine.

Comment: Presumably the random number has a seed based on the time and the serial number of the authenticator?

Answer (score 0):

If the security keys for this game work in the same way the security keys for other places work (World of Warcraft comes to mind), the key is tied to your account. You will need it every time you log in. However, uninstalling and reinstalling ("moving") the game should have no effect.

Comment: As a side note, my key is expected to arrive tomorrow, so I will be back then if this answer is not accurate and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When I set a mobile security key, it only works one time. I have to remove it then use a new one if I want to access something in the game that I need a security key for. You can get a mobile app that gives you security key numbers that connect to your online swtor account that you then log in with