# Is there a way to make the The Old Republic client log in automatically?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I use a password manager with 16 character random passwords for all my accounts. Currently, it's starting to get annoying to open my password manager, enter my master password, then copy my password manually to the The Old Republic client. Is there a way for the client to remember my password? Something like a hidden startup flag.

Comment: I don't believe there is such a hidden flag, but you could probably automate your existing process with AutoHotkey or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the KeePassx2 for passwords management and, from my perspective, it's not a problem to open vault and copy-past password, as it happens once a session. The flow is pretty much the same to what you described: master password -> copy -> paste -> press button.

As an option, you can roll with something like [XKCD passwords scheme ("correct horse battery staple scheme")](https://xkcd.com/936/) for SWTOR password and eliminate passwords manager as a step.

Also, I have [two-factor auth enabled with Android app](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43084/126370), so I have to also unlock my phone to get the security key. That's an extra step that also takes time.

Even if your new password is a bit weaker as a result, because as humans we're much worse at generating close-to-random passwords, two-factor auth will help you to keep your account secure enough.

Comment: I use 1Password, which is the same technique as you suggest in Keepass. I just want to avoid having to enter my master password every time I want to play the game.

Comment: @Nzall use a rememberable password (like what XKCD suggests) and back it up into 1pass. If you forget it, you can always take a look into the passwords vault. If you log into the game often enough that password manager is a problem, you'll soon remember your password pretty good.

Comment: For the reference, I use >10 words password to unencrypt my laptop on boot. It took me less than a week to remember it, especially if I don't have to remember a lot of passwords, 'cause of password manager taking care of them. :)